# Support vector based approach to density estimation

Tags: machine-learning, svm, references, density-estimation

I'm interested in the possiblity of using support vector machines for density estimation. The main source I found for this is a paper by Mukherjee & Vapnik 'Support vector method for multivariate density estimation' ([Link](http://www.ai.mit.edu/projects/ntt/projects/MIT2000-08/documents/dense_memo.ps)) which claims that this approach performs better than for example the Parzen-Window approach. The [scikit-learn documentation](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/svm.html#density-estimation-novelty-detection) mentions the possibility of using SVMs for this purpose, however there's no clear description of it to be found.

The paper by Mukherjee & Vapnik presents a different optimization problem that is to be solved using the support vector approach for this, while the scikit-learn documentation implies the use of one-class SVMs for this.

**Do these two approaches amount to different results?** Would an estimation as presented in the Mukherjee & Vapnik paper amount to the same as a one-class-SVM density estimation as shown in the scikit-learn example, if done for both classes in a binary problem?

I have failed to find a reference implementation of the approach by Mukherjee & Vapnik. **Is anyone aware of an implementation that I could have a look at?**

**Can anyone provide further material on this matter?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the two approaches are distinct. The paper by Mukherjee & Vapnik describes a method that is akin to a SVR of the empirical distribution function. They also have adaptive kernel width. Conversely one-class SVMs tries to build "a function
that takes the value +1 in a small region capturing most of the data points, and -1
elsewhere"  (see [Schölkopf et al.](https://papers.nips.cc/paper/1723-support-vector-method-for-novelty-detection.pdf)).

I am not aware of implementations of the former method and I have never seen it applied. Regarding one-class SVMs, they are widely used.

If you want to use them for density estimation, my guess would be that you should be able to use the values returned by `decision_function` of a one-class SVM to compute the pdf, after adding back the bias $\rho$ (which is effectively used in a one-class SVM as threshold for outlier detection) and scaling the result.

Looking at [sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/svm.cpp](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/4d9a12d175a38f2bcb720389ad2213f71a3d7697/sklearn/svm/src/libsvm/svm.cpp), we can see that (as expected) `decision_function` returns:

$$
h(\mathbf{x}) = \left[ \sum_{s \in \mathcal S} \alpha_s K(\mathbf{x}^{(s)},\mathbf{x}) \right] - \rho
$$
where $\mathcal S$ is the set of support vectors and $K()$ is
$$
K(\mathbf{x},\mathbf{z}) = \exp\left(-\gamma \, || \mathbf{x} - \mathbf{z} ||_2^2 \right).
$$

We need to add back $\rho$ so that what we obtain is an unnormalised mixture of $d$-dimensional multivariate Gaussians with covariance matrix $(2\gamma)^{-1} \mathbf{I}$.

Additionally, we need to normalise the result so that it integrates to one.
Each Gaussian in the summation above misses a normalisation factor:
$$
  \left(\frac{\gamma}{\pi}\right)^{d/2}
$$
which needs to be added back.
Also, the coefficients $\mathbf{\alpha}$ must add to one.

Overall, I think the density estimation can be computed as:
$$
p(\mathbf{x}) = \left(\frac{\gamma}{\pi}\right)^{d/2} \, |\mathbf{\alpha}|_1^{-1} \, (h(\mathbf{x}) + \rho)
$$

Something like (not tested):

```
n_dim = 2
gamma = ...
clf = svm.OneClassSVM(nu=..., kernel="rbf", gamma=gamma)
clf.fit(X_train)
xx, yy = np.meshgrid(np.linspace(...), np.linspace(...))
Z = clf.decision_function(np.c_[xx.ravel(), yy.ravel()])
Z = (Z - clf.intercept_[0]) * (gamma/np.pi)**(n_dim/2.) / np.sum(clf.dual_coef_)
Z.reshape(xx.shape)
plt.contourf(xx, yy, Z)
```

(Note: it looks like scikit-learn stores $-\rho$, rather than $\rho$, in `clf.intercept_[0]`.)